# Why can't you attack while invisible?

Tags: weapons, invisibility

In many sci-fi/fantasy settings, there are cloaking devices and invisibility spells that render the user invisible. However, they usually have the limitation, frequently for game-balancing purposes, that the user must de-cloak to attack. Suppose that there exists a typical sci-fi-style spaceship made of some material that allows light to pass directly through the ship when cloaking is enabled. Why and how might it have to de-cloak to fire its weapons?

**Edit**: To clarify, I'm looking for in-universe reasons. As noted above, this is almost always done in fiction because it would be either really overpowered (if only one side had stealth), or otherwise very boring (if both sides had stealth), but I'm not sure I've ever seen an explanation outside of "that's just the way stealth works in this universe".

Comment: Depends on the genre, for sci-fi thriller it serves to cut down budget. As for fantasy it is called convenient, in sci-fi horror it is called spooky action at a distance. Last but not least in children TV it is the "use-your-own-imagination-as-for-adults-get-lost!" effect!

Comment: Welcome to the site, Milo. The answer to your question is highly dependent on how invisibility functions, and there are a lot of models to choose from if we're considering all options. I would suggest defining which model you're interested in; as is, this is too broad.

Comment: In one word? *"Balance"*

Comment: Because that would be overpowered. If you're looking for a logical lore reason... Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Think of it as information control. Cloaking/invisibility is about limiting information about your location, appearance etc. Detection is about acquiring that information.
In a stable state, your cloaking restricts just enough information that detection can't find you. The moment you attack, you provide the detector with just enough additional information to locate you, even if it is only general direction.
Imagine a cloaked archer, for instance.As long as he is focused on being quiet and staying hidden, he won't be detected by the enemy. Now, if he decides to attack,he'll have to free his arms and string his bow. Both processes will cause noise, which can be picked up and the freed arms and light off the arrowhead can be spotted by a sharp eyed sentry.
Even assuming none of that happens, once he fires, if he hits and doesn't kill outright and the sentry isn't alone and unobserved, it's easy enough to figure out which direction the shot came from, and a guess of how far an arrow can be fired from, gives range and direction, that basically pinpoints the archer. If he misses, the sentry raises the alarm immediately. In the rare case that he one-shot-kills an isolated sentry, he may get away with it, but frankly, that happens only in movies,....or if the CO is an idiot.
The same principle applies to radar and stealth bombers. Even if the radar can't detect the bomber, once the bomb is dropped, the ground forces can guess what kind of bomb it is, which direction it came from and where the bomber could be. The error margin is high because of the speed of the bomber and the comparatively new technology, but given enough experience, the radar people will eventually be able to detect the bomber within seconds of the bay doors being opened. I believe it already IS possible, but not positive.
Melee attacks are obvious, so I'm not going into detail.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest explanation is that the invisibility isn't perfect, just advanced camouflage that is hard to notice unless you are looking carefully, but fast movements or getting too close to an enemy will make you noticeable and therefore visible.  This is the case with real-life camouflage, after all.

A more magical version of the same effect: the spell could make it that you aren't actually invisible, it just plays tricks on the minds of others so that they don't notice you.  But if you do something obvious enough or trigger the other person's defensive instinct by attacking them, that overrides the effect.

If you want this effect with true invisibility, the invisibility could rely on a "bubble" or "dome" placed around your body that must remain sealed; it isn't precise enough to actually wrap around your body's contours and limbs.  To fire a projectile weapon from inside the cloak, you need to make a hole in it, which nullifies the cloak.  If you get close enough to attack with melee, the enemy will either collide with or be inside the cloak, allowing them to see you.

Answer (score 1):

- I imagine something like the cloaked starships in Star Trek (and I haven't looked up any canon explanation for them) having a limited time of use. They would be a force-field which kept all energy inside and didn't allow anything to radiate out - i.e. the temperature would build up inside, and in order to make that last as long as possible they would have to lower heat and other emissions. At some point they would have to break the force field to avoid overheating.

  And therefore they would need to drop it to fire any weapon because otherwise that would be trapped inside as well, particularly energy beam weapons.
- Another way it might work is a phase-to-another-dimension approach, of the kind that lets characters walk through walls. You can't attack someone if you're not in the same physical dimension and cannot touch them.
- If it's a Harry Potter style cloak of invisibility - you can't easily attack someone and remain completely hidden while you're hiding under a blanket.
- Like IndigoFenix's answer about playing tricks on people's minds, there's one story where the characters can make other people lose eye focus and correspondingly lose concentration focus on the character and lose interest in them. That might be like stealth computer games - you are visible, but not noticeable. The guards hear you move, they say "*what was that?*" but if you hold still, the cloaking spell causes them to lose interest very quickly. But if you sneak up and wallop someone with a cudgel, they aren't going to lose interest in that for any amount of light attention changing.
- The way ordinary people try to be stealthy is to tread lightly, breathe gently, move slowly, stick to the shadows. If it's a basic kind of stealth spell, what it could do is enforce and boost those tendencies - forces you to tread lightly and breathe gently, suppresses any sudden or fast movements or reactions, boosts your desire to stay in the shadows and heightens your awareness of other people, their position, their attention, makes you extra avoidant about noise making things (twigs, movements, lose pebbles). So with that working on you, you wouldn't be physically able to perform an attack, and wouldn't be mentally willing to.

Comment: Star Trek canon is that cloaking devices can't operate with shields. In Star Trek from sustaining a hit while unshielded means it's pretty much game over.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Predator]

Even the youngest [Yautja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predator_(alien)) knows, that blood splatters from game scored spoils the camouflage. And cloaking devices operates quite slow, and sometimes cannot render the view properly, especially when you are moving fast and close to game. Making it perfect is very non honourable thing, that spoils Hunt. Game needs to have chances.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentionned, it s mostly for game-balancing purpose.

In practice a cloaking device would work like this. It would be like a wearable bendable screen covering your entire body. It would film what s around you and display it on the screen. It would be similar to how a cameleon hides himself but much better. You won't be invisisible but from a distance you ll be so well camouflaged that it s as if you were invisible (in the visible spectrum of light at least)

I don't see why moving would suddenly dispell your invisibility. It will however make you less camouflaged for sure since your movement might reveal your position.

Note that such a cloaking device actually exists in some labs. It s still in its infancy so you are not cloaked like Predator but eventually we ll get there.

http://www.tokyotimes.com/japan-invents-invisibility-cloak/

Answer (score 0):

One way a cloaking device could work, would be to adjust the local gravity in such a way that light bends around the object that is cloaked. That would require a substantial adjustment to local gravity and although this would be highly contained, anything you tried to push through it would plausibly fall right back in.

Even if it operates on a different basis, there is a good chance that the cloaking device works to redirect energy around the object cloaked in some way and it would be quite plausible that any energy based weaponry launched from within a cloaking field would be affected by the field, making it basically impossible to aim them with any accuracy. Additionally, a patch of empty space that starts spraying energy fire out in arbitrary directions is going to be a pretty clear giveaway for your cloaked ship.